# How to make a webbuild for iOS via itune

Tags: xcode, xcode4

my archieved file is in .ipa format, now i want to make a web built so that other's can test it. can someone guide me on how to achieve this or simply show me a tutorial where i can make a webbuild of my .ipa file ? Sorry but it is my first iphone application development and i don't find a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a web build of an iPhone app.

In order for others to test your app, they will need to provide the UUID of their phone to you. You then add the UUIDs (up to 100) on the provisioning portal and create a new certificate for ad-hoc distribution. With that certificate, you build a .ipa file. Finally, you send the certificate and the .ipa file to your users (or make it available on a web site). They then can drag it into iTunes and synchronize their phone.

If more users want to join the test, you will need to create a new certificate and a new .ipa file. It's not possible to have a public test. It's always a closed user group.

Comment: but how to drag it to itune ?

Comment: First, you need to download/save the file somewhere in a folder. Then you open both iTunes and a window for the folder. Then you select the .ipa file in one window and drag it onto the iTunes window. In the old iTunes, you had the drag the file in an area in the top left corner of the windows. I haven't tried it with the latest iTunes yet.

Comment: is there a specific path to drag the .ipa into itune ? i am draging it but it returns to the folder.. so its not working .. i think its a new version of itunes

Comment: It seems that with iTunes 11, you have to use the menu *File* / *Add File To The Library* and then select your ipa file.

Comment: i need to enter my apple username + id ? to share it

Comment: How do you want to share it? You shouldn't need your Apple ID because the *sharing* is not directly supported by Apple.